# .addClass not working on individual Spans

Tags: jquery

```
$(event.currentTarget).closest('.segment').find('span').addClass('hide')
```

I have written this line on `click` function and it works fine. The issue is that it works on all the three spans that it returns. I want only the second span to add class of HIDE. If i try the below code it says the `.addClass()` is not a function.

```
$(event.currentTarget).closest('.segment').find('span')[0].addClass('hide')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method / [`:eq(index)` selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) instead of `[0]`.

Since `[0]` returns the reference of DOM element which doesn't have the method thus it throws the error.

```
$(event.currentTarget).closest('.segment').find('span').eq(0).addClass('hide')
$(event.currentTarget).closest('.segment').find('span:eq(0)').addClass('hide')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to target span at specific index you can also use :nth-child selector.

```
$(event.currentTarget).closest('.segment').find('span:nth-child(2)').addClass('hide')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried eq? Maybe something like this:

```
$(event.currentTarget).closest('.segment').find('span:eq(1)').addClass('hide');
```